# HTTP a HTTPS Ubuntu 20.04 Lamp Droplet Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, http, ssl, https, digitalocean

he desarrollado una API en Laravel, e hice el despliegue en Ubuntu 20.04 en un Droplet de Digital Ocean, está funcionando todo correcto la API, pero necesito pasar de http a https en la documentación me pide que use Certbot y estado intentando pasar, pero no me funciona alguien que recomiende como hacer, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas! Aquí tengo un link que te podría facilitar la búsqueda. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04-es